# What is a term to denote someone who is obsessed with or erudite in geography?

Tags: terminology

What is a good term to denote someone who is obsessed with, or erudite in, geography?

Comment: Perhaps a cartophile? That's not in my dictionary, but it feels ripe for coining even if it does not in fact exist.

Comment: @Robusto: but wouldn't *cartophile* only imply an obsession with maps in particular?

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Well, 'geography' comes from the Greek for 'earth' + 'writing', so I can't imagine maps aren't central to the pursuit.

Comment: This should be asked on the GIS forum, where the geographils hang out.

Comment: I think the properly constructed word would be *geographomaniac* (γεω = *Earth*, γράφειν = *write*, μανία = *madness, frenzy, enthusiasm*).

Comment: "Cartophile" seems an excellent word to me. It does get over 46,000 hits on Yahoo.

Comment: Possibly good enough - [maphead](http://www.ken-jennings.com/maphead)

Comment: @RegDwigнt, I wonder, though, is this guy crazy about geography or geographers?

Comment: Being obsessed with something and being erudite in it are two rather different things, as far as naming it is concerned.

Comment: I would say "geographite".

Comment: sorry, I meant as far as naming _them_ is concerned

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Geographer.

[Geographer on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographer): A geographer is a scientist whose area of study is geography, the study of Earth's physical environment and human habitat.

I'd suggest that, while this doesn't exactly apply to obsessives, it certainly would apply to the erudite and those who are generally very interested in geography.

Answer (score -1):

## Geographile (deprecated) or Geographophile!

If one is going to create a word, one might as well go for the more direct route.

While I couldn't find a respected source for this nonce word (Geographile), a Google search did result in >12k results (likely, in part, to several social media platforms having a user with this moniker.)

Geographophile, on the other hand, produced exactly "About 7 results" from Google, but may be the more correct, if rarer, nonce word.

Use either at your own pleasure / risk. :-)

Comment: are you a haplographile?

Comment: @Toothrot - Why the downvote?  And, no, not to my knowledge.  Why?  Do you believe I misspelled Geographile?  Or are you just generally dissatisfied with the notion of nonce words?

Comment: because it would have had to be _geographophile;_ you committed a haplography.  though I'm unsure if _geographophile_ would refer to a lover of geography or of geographers or if it could refer to both.

Comment: @Toothrot - I defer to your superior knowledge in this matter.  Thanks! 

Comment: @Toothrot - Sorted!